# Revoke permissions to data granted to user SDE gives "Invalid use of GRANT/REVOKE function" error

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, permission

I inherited an Oracle geodatabase where user SDE was granted indiscriminately to data in other schemas. I would like to revoke the privileges, but for some feature classes/datasets I am getting "Invalid use of GRANT/REVOKE function" when attempting this in ArcCatalog. I think the difference is the age of the data; SDE doesn't want to release its hold on the ancient data, but on newer stuff in other schemas I can grant/revoke to SDE at will.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: *"Never anthropomorphize inanimate objects. They hate it when you do that."* It's certainly not the SDE user which wants to retain access. It's likely that the permissions you are trying to revoke through ArcGIS were never assigned through ArcGIS in the first place, so it doesn't know how to revoke them.

Comment: @Vince .. that sounds very likely. Thank you for the suggestion